# Why did the Vilna Sha"s become so widespread?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, jewish-books

If one enters a beit midrash and takes out a masechta of Talmud, one will invariably find that it is typeset following the exact form of the page found in the edition from Vilna.

So here are two questions about that:

1. Why did the Vilna edition become so widespread?
2. When did it supersede other editions as the primary version of the Talmud?

Comment: The story of the vilna and slavita shas is well documented. Almost all the rabbonim in the world took sides. At the end R Akiva Eiger approved the Vilna shas.

Comment: @cham, that was a different sha"s. It was also published by Romm, but it was an earlier edition (On the Mainline has a wonderful blog about the Acharit Davar to the more notable Vilna Sha"s: http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/03/vagshals-revision-of-history-of-vilna.html)

Comment: Once the Romm brothers had the rights to be the only printers for several years, they had the monopoly.

Comment: @HaLeiVi, That doesn't explain why it's used so commonly by Sephardim and western/central Europeans

Comment: They were the only printers. It was a heavy investment. It took many years to produce. There was little room for startups.

Comment: @HaLeiVi They were the only printers in **Russia**. There were numerous other printers throughout the Jewish world at the time.

Comment: Are you really sure there are other prints? Even now, there is a very limited selection of old prints in Otzar Hasfarim.

Comment: @HaLeiVi, considering that the western European printers used higher quality materials (I have some Romm books which are of significantly lower quality than my western books, like my Wien Tanach) and that most German Jews would not have wished to show that they were using Russian books, as their countries really didn't have the best diplomatic relations (and other societal factors).

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer,_Collected_Responsa.57.5

Comment: There were still other versions being printed here in America up until a couple decades ago. Berman was still printing a variant tzuras hadaf. Popularity is not always something you can pin a tag on.

Comment: Because Because Because Because Because Because

Answer (score 2):

The [Vilna Shas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Edition_Shas) is relatively recent (it was published in 1886). It was the most extensive Talmud ever printed at that time, including dozens of early commentaries printed for the first time from manuscripts, as well as later commentaires, all painstakingly edited by *talmidei chachamim*. It took them six years to prepare the new edition. As such it was a **superior product**, and was highly successful.

In parallel, their **main competitor**, the [Slavita Shas](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/501896/the-slavuta-shas.html) **had sold out** by 1835, and for different reasons that printing house was shut down by the government.

Add to this the **power of memorization** (*talmidei chachamim* know where on the page specific citations/commentaries are) which helped make it the standard.

Interestingly, the printing of the Vilna Shas was done on a "[Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com)-like model": due to the substantial costs involved in the editing and printing, the publishers issued a notice to the public announcing their Talmud, together with a sample, and asking for pre-commitments to purchase it when it appeared. Response was overwhelmingly positive and launched the venture. The **high investment required** was another barrier to entry for competitors.

Finally, soon enough, **Europe got engulfed in World War 1** and following, which massively restricted printing of new books. New editions of the Talmud only restarted to be prepared after the end of WW2.

The factbase above leverages Akiva Aaronson's [People of the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598269569), a wonderful book about Jewish books. See also [here](http://strangeside.com/talmud-the-vilna-shas/) for further reading.

Comment: There were many other prints in Austria and Germany, so I suppose the key factor is the first. Despite the censorship, the quality of the Vilna Shas is very high, it's relatively free of typos, which was a big achievement in that period. And it's not independent from the fact that the centre of Talmudic knowledge moved to that region over the centuries from other parts of Europe.

Comment: When you say print do you mean printers? And if yes did they have the resources to prepare their own shas?

Comment: Anton Schmid in Vienna had three editions of the Talmud, and I'm sure there were others.

Comment: @Kazibácsi according to [this](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=OKSODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA201&dq=anton%20schmid%20talmud&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q=anton%20schmid%20talmud&f=false) the last Anton Schmid edition was in 1849. The Vilna Shas was finished in 1886. I was referring to the fact there were no other major new edition of the Vilna Shas after it closed due to WW1/WW2

Comment: I've just found this mentioned in the same book: https://www.kedem-auctions.com/product/tractate-brachot-%E2%80%93-vienna-1860-%E2%80%93-glosses/